# How to give a shadow to the end-edge with D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have an Apple Rings - JS stuff running [here](https://codepen.io/satishsainicode/pen/LYyOYmX)

[image]

I want to show a shadow at the end of the circle if value crosses 100%
For e.g. `{index: 2, name: 'stand', icon: "\uF106", percentage: 120}`

Can someone help me to suggest what needs to be changed in D3.js code to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: you could add/remove a class to apply the shadow if the value is highher or lower than 100. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGWLyqr

Comment: Yeah! I found that link and it helped me :)